# How to Use Push Notifications With FireBase Updated

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase

I am currently trying to setup Push Notifications and allthough xcode believes there is no issue in the code the feauture is not working if anyone can see any issues or has an suggestions for other places a problem could be it would be greatly appreciated.

```
 //
//  AppDelegate.swift
//  PushMyNotifs
//
//  Created by Jack Wallace on 24/6/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 JackWallace. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseInstanceID
import FirebaseMessaging
import UserNotifications

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, 
UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?


func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {


    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
            options: authOptions,
            completionHandler: {_, _ in })
        // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
    } else {
        let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
            UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    }

    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()


    FirebaseApp.configure()



    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.tokenRefreshNotification(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.InstanceIDTokenRefresh, object: nil)

    return true

}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {

    Messaging.messaging().shouldEstablishDirectChannel = false

}

func tokenRefreshNotification(notification: NSNotification){

    let refreshedToken = InstanceID.instanceID().token()!

    print("InstanceID token: \(refreshedToken)")

    connectToFCM()

}



func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didRefreshRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {

    print("Firebase registration token: \(fcmToken)")

}



func connectToFCM(){

    Messaging.messaging().shouldEstablishDirectChannel = false

    }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you setup your certificate ?

Here is a nice example :
[push-notifications-in-firebase](http://agostini.tech/2017/06/18/push-notifications-in-firebase/?utm_content=buffer8b5c2&utm_medium=social&utm_source=linkedin.com&utm_campaign=buffer)